# In VB, setting parameters of command object seems to fail

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net, parameter-passing

I use the following VB code to execute a scalar function on my sql server:

```
cmd.CommandText = "[STFRA].[dbo].MyScalarFunc"

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fastener", SqlDbType.Int)
        cmd.Parameters("@Fastener").Value = 4148
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Thickness", SqlDbType.Float)
        cmd.Parameters("@Thickness").Value = 3.2
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Material", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10)
        cmd.Parameters("@Material").Value = a
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Shear", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2)
        cmd.Parameters("@Shear").Value = 1


        Dim retObj As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar(cmd)
```

As error message i get back: The Procedure or function  'MyScalarFunc' expects the parameter '@Fastener'-Parameter, which was not provided.
Parameter names, order and types are exactly the same as on the server. When watching cmd in the watchlist i can see that 4 parameters are appended to it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try running a [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091(v=SQL.100).aspx) trace and capture the **RPC:Starting** EventClass to see what parameters are being passed to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in a while, but are you sure you need to add the @ symbols to the parameter names in VB?  This is a SQL Server syntax.  Just do:

```
     cmd.CommandText = "[STFRA].[dbo].MyScalarFunc"
     cmd.Parameters.Add("Fastener", SqlDbType.Int)
     cmd.Parameters("Fastener").Value = 4148
     cmd.Parameters.Add("Thickness", SqlDbType.Float)
     cmd.Parameters("Thickness").Value = 3.2
     cmd.Parameters.Add("Material", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10)
     cmd.Parameters("Material").Value = a
     cmd.Parameters.Add("Shear", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2)
     cmd.Parameters("Shear").Value = 1
     Dim retObj As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandTypes.StoredProcudure
```